# SQL SELECT FROM RESULT OF A QUERY IN FROM

Tags: sql

I'm trying to SELECT records from another query in FROM clause.

```
Ex: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.COL_3=3) B WHERE B.COL_2!=1
```

Query in FROM clause is returning 6 records with A.COL_2 having value of 1. But when SELECT on B is done with condition COL_2 NOT EQUAL to 1, I'm getting same records which I got for query in FROM clause with value of COL_2 as null.

This is on informix data base.

Actual query -

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT CASE NVL(A.CST_CD,-1)
          WHEN -1 THEN (SELECT 1
                          FROM SOEVNT B
                         WHERE B.KNBR 
                                = CAST(CONCAT(CAST(A.RNBR AS INTEGER),
                                         CASE
                                      WHEN A.RC_NBR >0 AND A.RC_NBR <10
                                      THEN CONCAT('0000',A.RC_NBR)
                                      WHEN A.RC_NBR >9 AND A.RC_NBR <100
                                      THEN CONCAT('000',A.RC_NBR)
                                      WHEN A.RC_NBR >99 AND A.RC_NBR <1000
                                      THEN CONCAT('00',A.RC_NBR)
                                     WHEN A.RC_NBR >999 AND A.RC_NBR <10000
                                      THEN CONCAT('0',A.RC_NBR)
                                      ELSE CAST(A.RC_NBR AS CHAR(5)) 
                                      END) AS INTEGER) 
                             AND B.MTE_EVNT = 'RG'
                             AND B.SO_LINE_NBR = D.DTL_SEQ_NBR)
         ELSE 0
        END AS SOEVNT_1,
        CASE NVL(A.CST_CD,-1)
             WHEN -1 THEN (SELECT 1
                             FROM SOEVNT B
                            WHERE B.KNBR = CAST(CONCAT(CAST(A.RNBR AS INTEGER),
                                           CASE
                                          WHEN A.RC_NBR >0 AND A.RC_NBR <10
                                          THEN CONCAT('0000',A.RC_NBR)
                                          WHEN A.RC_NBR >9 AND A.RC_NBR <100
                                          THEN CONCAT('000',A.RC_NBR)
                                          WHEN A.RC_NBR >99 AND A.RC_NBR <1000
                                          THEN CONCAT('00',A.RC_NBR)
                                          WHEN A.RC_NBR >999 AND A.RC_NBR <10000
                                          THEN CONCAT('0',A.RC_NBR)
                                          ELSE CAST(A.RC_NBR AS CHAR(5)) END) 
                                           AS   INTEGER)
                              AND B.MTE_EVNT = 'K')
                               ELSE 0
         END AS SOEVNT_2, 
      A.RNBR, 
      A.APTYP,
      A.ORNBR, 
      A.RC_NBR,
      NVL(A.CST_CD,-1) AS CSTYP,
      CASE A.CST_CD WHEN 0 THEN 'YR2' 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'OSE' ELSE 'LEG' END AS ORDTYP,
      D.DSNBR,
      A.CTTS,
      (SELECT PO_STAT_CD FROM STR_PO C 
         WHERE C.PO_CTRL_NBR = A.ORD_NBR AND C.APTYP = A.APTYP) AS POSTAT, 
      D.RQTY, A.DRETS
FROM SR A, OUTER (SRS D)
WHERE A.APTYP = 5
 AND A.RTYP != 10
 AND ( DATE(A.DRETS) > TODAY-20) 
         AND A.RC_NBR = D.RC_NBR AND D.RQTY > 0
) WHERE SOEVNT_1 != 1
```

Result of query in FROM clause when executed seperately-

```
soevnt_1 soevnt_2 rnbr aptyp ornbr  rc_nbr cstyp ordtyp dsnbr ctts postat rqty drets
1          NULL  0077   5    51003  79978   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      1 2013-10-14 06:01:54.634
1          NULL  0077   5    51011  79966   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      7 2013-10-03 05:21:06.493
1          NULL  0077   5    51012  79967   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      5 2013-10-03 06:02:43.133
1          NULL 0077    5    51012  79981   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      1 2013-10-17 14:39:25.295
1          NULL 0077    5    51013  79968   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      1 2013-10-03 14:51:50.132
1          NULL 0077    5    51015  79969   -1  LEG      1   NULL  3      5 2013-10-04 03:59:09.835
```

Result set when complete query executed

```
soevnt_1 soevnt_2 rnbr aptyp ornbr  rc_nbr cstyp ordtyp dsnbr ctts postat rqty drets
NULL      NULL    0077  5    51003  79978   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-14 06:01:54.634
NULL      NULL    0077  5    51011  79966   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-03 05:21:06.493
NULL      NULL    0077  5    51012  79967   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-03 06:02:43.133
NULL      NULL    0077  5    51012  79981   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-17 14:39:25.295
NULL     NULL     0077  5    51013  79968   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-03 14:51:50.132
NULL     NULL     0077  5    51015  79969   -1   LEG    NULL  NULL  3     NULL 2013-10-04 03:59:09.835
```

Comment: @AVVD I tried to give your post a good format, but I quit it. My impression your query is totally improper regardless what you're trying to achieve. Probably, you should look for another approach...

Comment: What's up with the uppercase?

Comment: Nothing specific with upper case.

Comment: I formatted it to more readable. What is wrong with the query? I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of an old bug in informix 7.3 with subqueries where it would ignore fields.

In your particular query i'd try this:

- give a field name to SELECT 1... Maybe informix is being picky about this
- Create a view (this is actually a good idea regardless of your problem, since you abstract your subquery away, and its available to others)
- If you can use a stored procedure, a SELECT ... INTO TEMP is a good idea too.

Comment: I tried giving all the column names in the select[outside] . It didn't work. I'm just a db user who can query database. I can neither create views nor run stored procedures.

Comment: But I made one change. It started working. I removed the outer join inside. I'm not sure how it makes difference.